Female Nazi agent with sex scenes movie (1960-1980)
An unforgettable scene in this movie is when a beautiful female Nazi/Gestapo/SS agent takes her own virginity with a phallus while she's sitting nude in a bathtub. Blood can then be seen in the water. In another scene, the Nazi captain says to her, "You are our best agent". I saw it around 1980 but it might have been made anytime between 1960-1980. The language was English, but maybe it was dubbed and I didn't realize it. It was in color.

What language was it in?

I don't recall the exact scene you mention but Mata Hari (1985) has a great Nazi lesbian sex scene. It is a soft core porn movie with lots of other similar scenes that might include the one you are talking about, and the subject matter certainly sounds similar.
